# Element positioning with css

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I have three divs inside of which there are two elements, one is an image and the other one is an h3 tag inside another div.
I have created a class for positioning the h3 tag to the center of the image. However when I apply the class to those divs, the h3 is positioned in the centre but not in the case of the first div, it is way more above the image.

Below is the code snippet:

```css
/* the class for positioning */

.tagline {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
}


/* CSS for the divs */

.mobile-category-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-category-wrapper">
  <img src="img/places.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="tagline">
    <h3>Places</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-category-wrapper">
  <img src="img/people.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="tagline">
    <h3>People</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-category-wrapper">
  <img src="img/events.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="tagline">
    <h3>Events</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is what I want to achieve and its the second div.

[image]
This is the first div where the h3 goes way up.
[image]

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you have more CSS, can you create a working code with image we can see

Comment: CSS for `mobile-category-wrapper` with position = relative was my first thought but you have that. A screenshot of what is occurring would be helpful

Comment: I have tried the above code in js fiddle everything works fine, but not in the actual file. I have rechecked and made sure no other rules are in conflict with it as the other two divs give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have invalid CSS for the divs -- if this is sass, you can precompile; however, normal CSS shouldn't nest a selector

CSS for the divs:

```
.mobile-category-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Should be two rules

```
.mobile-category-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.mobile-category-wrapper img {
        width: 100%;
}
```

For the remaining issue with translation, I would recommend explicitly adding an origin to see if this fixes the issue:

```
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Safari 3-8 */
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: I am using sass